# Exchange 2007 - send from any domain address

Tags: permissions, exchange-2007

Forgive my ignorance, it's been a *long* time since I've done much Exchange work.

We have an SMTP connector set up for our legacy app on the web server, it's all locked down to specific IP addresses and whatnot, but we use a lot of throwaway addresses that we don't want to receive email on.

How can I set up an exchange account to have permission to send as `*@example.com` (even when the address does not exist in the exchange server)? I know it can be done because I used to have it done on our old Exchange server, but I'm just having a mental blank today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sam Cogan's answer, I found the correct permission to apply:

```
Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Sender
```

In the form of:

`Get-ReceiveConnector "connector name" | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Sender"`

As descibed on [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996395.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your going to need to create a send connector that allows anonymous relaying, but restrict it to just the IP of the app server.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.petri.co.il/authenticated-or-anonymous-smtp-relay-with-exchange-2007.htm) for some details on how to do it (the bottom section labled Anonymous relays)

Comment: Wasn't 100% what I wanted, but it put me on the right path! Thanks heaps.